# Windows phone create animation of controls

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I need to load some images and show on grid (with simple animation). I have

```
            Image img = IconWithId(i);
            // set some properties
            //...
            img.Tap += img_Tap;
            img.ImageOpened += img_ImageOpened;
            gameView.Children.Add(img);
```

In event img_ImageOpened i create animation

```
void img_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = sender as Image;
        Storyboard story = new Storyboard();

        DoubleAnimation dAnimation = new DoubleAnimation();
        dAnimation.From = 0;
        dAnimation.To = 1;
        dAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        Storyboard.SetTarget(dAnimation, img);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(dAnimation, new PropertyPath(OpacityProperty));

        story.Children.Add(dAnimation);

        story.Begin();
    }
```

I think i have animation which should show image but it don't work. Image loaded without animation. What can i do?
PS i need to animation when images will close. I think to use event unloaded
Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code on a Windows Phone 8 with Phone 8 SDK

Your code works perfectly fine.

You need to change the duration to a longer period.  100ms way too fast.  You won't be able to see it quick enough.

Change it to something longer like this

```
dAnimation.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
```